# Issue in configuring spring security 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I googled and searched on stackoverflow but I had no success

I'm trying to setup spring security in my web app. I'm using and embedded jetty and these spring versions:

- spring applicationframework 4.3.5
- spring security 4.2.1
- tiles 3

I wrote the following security config (a very simple one)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityCfg extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/adminWebTheme/**")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/pages/**")
        .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/pages/loginPage")
        .permitAll()
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/pages/adminHome")
        .failureUrl("/pages/loginPage?error=true")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/pages/loginPage?logout=true")
        .and()
        .csrf();

    }
}
```

This is my security initializer

```
public class WebSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{

}
```

Basically I want to use my custom login form.
This is my login JSP body:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<tiles:insertDefinition name="loginPageTemplate">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="head">
        <title><spring:message code="comm.server.login.page.title" /></title>
    </tiles:putAttribute>
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><spring:message code="comm.server.login.msg" /></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <c:if test="${not empty param.error && param.error }">
                                <div class="alert alert-error">    
                                    <spring:message code="comm.server.login.error.msg" />
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${not empty param.logout && param.logout }">
                                <div class="alert alert-succes">    
                                    <spring:message code="comm.server.login.logout.msg" />
                                </div>
                            </c:if>     
                            <form role="form" method="post" action='<spring:url value="/login" />'>
                                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>.
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                        <label class="input-group-addon" for="username"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder='<spring:message code="comm.server.login.username.placeholder" />' name="username" id="username"
                                            type="text" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                        <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder='<spring:message code="comm.server.login.password.placeholder" />'
                                            name="password" id="password" type="password" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label> <input name="remember" id="remember" type="checkbox"
                                            value='<spring:message code="comm.server.login.rememberme" />'><spring:message code="comm.server.login.rememberme" />
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                    <!-- <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a> -->
                                    <button id="accedi" name="accedi" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"><spring:message code="comm.server.login.button" /></button>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

From the previous code it seems to me all correct. I tried the access to the login page and i can access to the page successfully.
Now I have 2 kind of problem:

1. If i try to access to the page ..../pages/adminHome the login page is not showed
2. If I put username and password in my login page, the submit to the url "/login" fails because it tells me no login url is found

By the previous behaviour it's like is spring secuirty is not called at all and i can't figure the reasong
When I start my application i see the following logs:

```
2017-01-01 12:11:47,470 5469 [main] INFO  org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess - Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
2017-01-01 12:11:47,522 5521 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.c.a.a.c.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer - Eagerly initializing {webSecurityCfg=it.eng.tz.comm.svr.web.config.WebSecurityCfg$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26b9578a@16a49a5d}
2017-01-01 12:11:47,679 5678 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for ExactUrl [processUrl='/pages/loginPage?error=true']
2017-01-01 12:11:47,680 5679 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for ExactUrl [processUrl='/pages/loginPage']
2017-01-01 12:11:47,681 5680 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for ExactUrl [processUrl='/pages/loginPage']
2017-01-01 12:11:47,682 5681 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2017-01-01 12:11:47,682 5681 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for ExactUrl [processUrl='/pages/loginPage?logout=true']
2017-01-01 12:11:47,682 5681 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/adminWebTheme/**']
2017-01-01 12:11:47,683 5682 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'hasRole('ADMIN')', for Ant [pattern='/pages/**']
2017-01-01 12:11:47,693 5692 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
2017-01-01 12:11:47,695 5694 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
2017-01-01 12:11:47,713 5712 [main] INFO  o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3a175162, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@18acfe88, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7fd8c559, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5c534b5b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3a543f31, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7569ea63, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@772861aa, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7c1e32c9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1640190a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@8f2098e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@53ed09e8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4743a322]
```

Now it seems to me all correctly configured.... but i can't protect my web application
Can anybody help me?

Thank you
Angelo

**UPDATED AS SUGGESTED**

As suggested I modified my Spring security configuration by doing:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/adminWebTheme/**")
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/pages/**")
    .authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/pages/**")
    .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/pages/loginPage")
    .permitAll()
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/pages/adminHome")
    .failureUrl("/pages/loginPage?error")
    .and()
    .logout()
    .permitAll()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/pages/loginPage?logout")
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/pages/accessDenied");

}
```

Nothing changed. It seems to me like if Spring security filter doesn't intercept urls... and I don't know the reason. I'm sure it's a configuration issue but I can't figure where I'm wrong...

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

I figured what I was missing

I'm using and embedded Jetty where I manually added the spring dispatcher servlet
So I had to add the Spring security filter too....
In my jetty I added the following (the most important thing is the secFilter section):

```
DispatcherServlet springSvlt = new DispatcherServlet(context);
        contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(springSvlt), MAPPING_URL);
        contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
        //Filtro eTag
        ServletHandler sh = new ServletHandler();
        FilterHolder eTagFilter = sh.addFilterWithMapping(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        contextHandler.addFilter(eTagFilter, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        //Filtro Gzip
        FilterHolder gZipFilter = sh.addFilterWithMapping(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        gZipFilter.setInitParameter("varyHeader", "true");
        contextHandler.addFilter(gZipFilter, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
//      //Filtro sicurezza
        FilterHolder secFilter = new FilterHolder( new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain") ); 
        contextHandler.addFilter(secFilter, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

Now it works correctly

Thank you to all and I hope this can be useful

Angelo